# ComponentOne.TrueDBGrid binding

Tags: list, generics, binding, componentone, truedbgrid

## 1 I am using ComponentOne.TrueDBGrid;

## 2 I am using UserList as the datasource;

## 3 I need filterbar and sortings for this grid ;

some important code like below:
public class User{
    public int UserID{get;set;}
    public string UserName{get;set;}
    public Company TheCompany{get;set;}
}

public class Company{
    public override ToString(){
        return CompanyName;
    }
    public string CompanyName{get;set;}
}

List UserList

Question:

## 1 How can I bind UserList to the TrueDBGrid to show these Columns ?

|UserID|UserName|CompanyName|
   I think these datafields should be UserID , UserName, TheCompany.CompanyName，But I can't see the CompanyName is empty;

## 2 I need change Company in this grid , so I need I add valueItems for CompanyName

```
   I think these datafields should be UserID , UserName, TheCompany，and override Company.ToString() = CompanyName 
   But I can't sorting the companyName column and can't change company because the datatype is string can't covert to Company;
```

Is these a good way to resolve these problems ?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but...

Add a readonly string property to UserList that returns TheCompany.CompanyName.